# Return last SELECT value from stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm using **SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar** in C# to get the result of stored procedure in Microsoft SqlServer. The result should be set by the last command of stored procedure - "SELECT something".

It works correctly with one SELECT command in procedure. However when there are more SELECTs in stored procedure it goes wrong. It seems that the result of first SELECT is returned:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure AS      
  BEGIN
  SELECT 'A'
  SELECT 'B"
  END
```

Execution of it will return 'A' through ExecuteScalar

I'm using someone's else procedures and he's using a lot of SELECT commands in it, apparently for testing in Sql Magagement Studio. I rather can't change them.

Am I able to get the value from final SELECT?

Comment: Instead of `ExecuteScalar` you could use `ExecuteReader` and then `NextResult`.

Comment: You need to use [`SqlCommand.NextResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) to get the next result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`SqlDataReader.NextResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) to get the next result set. It returns a `boolean` value to indicate if there is a next one. To get the last one, just keep calling `NextResult` until it returns `false`.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.NextResult())
{
    //We still haven't reached the last result set yet...
}
```

Comment: @Blam Which is exactly what is being asked! :)

Comment: But he does not want to break what is working.  "It works correctly with one SELECT command in procedure."

Comment: @Blam And this code works correctly when there is one SELECT in the procedure too. OP only ever wants to see the very last SELECT result.

Answer (score 1):

```
do {   while (reader.Read()) 
       { 
           // TODO: read away
       }
   }   while (reader.NextResult())
```